# Unplugged my cable while upgrading via Odin

Tags: unbricking, odin

My cable was unplugged while my Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100 upgrading with Odin. Now, nothing appears on the screen, even when I plug the charger. How can I fix my device?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting into the Download mode and trying the upgrade again?

Comment: Exactely! But now Nothing appear on the screen , even if I plug the charger

Answer (score -1):

You will have to Switch ON the phone in "Safe Mode" by pressing the <kbd>Volume down</kbd>, <kbd>Power</kbd>, and the <kbd>Home</kbd> button all together. Then, factory reset the phone, and upgrade it through Odin; or on a safer side, use Samsung Kies for upgrading to a new OS.

Comment: Thank you so much! but i tried to do this and nothing happen. nothing appears on the screen! I can say that the phone can not turn on. When i plug the charger nothing appears! What could you advise me in this way!!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Connect your phone to ur PC through kies ! And then see if it discovers the device...download the ROM that is officially launhed for your phone (through sammobile if u have samsung android samrtphone ) and restore that to your phone !

Comment: On your phone in safe mode by using ..." Lock +Volume Up + home " for some seconds !!